# Editing And Searching Inside Of String Arrays

Tags: java, arrays, string, search, edit

Sorry about the formatting disaster, I'm new to stackoverflow  and Java. I have two issues inside of a code that is supposed to contain two lists of names and corresponding catalog #s. Inside the code I am supposed to be able to search, display, edit, and quit. Display and quit already work, but I have an issue with search and edit. I have highlighted information where the issue is. I would appreciate any help.

```
public static void Search(String[] arr, String find) {

    for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
```

//First issue!! This is my method to call upon later that searches within a String Array for bits of code. I need to be able to search within the array for certain characters (the arrays are names, so “mith” would bring up “smith”. Later in the code I call on this inside of a switch. I think I need something like "arr[i].equals(find)" but I can't figure out the syntax

```
   }
}

public static void main(String[] args) {

    Scanner inp = new Scanner(System.in);
    String userInput1 = "";
    String userInput2 = "";
    String userInput3 = "";

    // Ask User to chose between faculty and students
    System.out.println("Are you searching for Students or Faculty? ");
    userInput1 = inp.nextLine().toLowerCase();


    if (userInput1.startsWith("f")) {

        //Block 1 for faculty
        do {

            String[] Faculty = {"0. Jack Kerouac", "1. Les Claypool", "2. Tom Waits", "3. Kurt Vonnegut",
                "4. Hunter Thompson", "5. Princess Bubblegum", "6. John Smith", "7. Jack Thompson", "8. Jeff Dahmer", "9. Martin King"};


            System.out.println("What would you like to do?");
            System.out.println("S: Search");
            System.out.println("E: Edit");
            System.out.println("D: Display");
            System.out.println("Q: Quit");

            // user input
            userInput2 = inp.nextLine().toLowerCase();
            System.out.println("");

            // Respond based on user input
            switch (userInput2.charAt(0)) {
                case 's':
                    System.out.println("Type part of the persons name: ");
                    String x = inp.nextLine().toLowerCase();
                    String[] y = Faculty;
                    Search(y, x);
                break;
                case 'e':
```

//This is my editing arrays issue comes in. I've attempted a couple different methods to get this to work but in each one I run into a problem when reassigning the Faculty[q]. When you run the program it skips from “Enter new catalog information” back to the main loop. How do I change the string inside of my array?

```
                    System.out.println("Enter the catalog number of the entry trying to edit: ");
                    int q = inp.nextInt();
                    System.out.println(Faculty[q]);
                    System.out.println("Enter new catalog information: ");                       
                    String NewFac = inp.nextLine();
                    Faculty[q] = String NewFac;
                    System.out.println(Faculty[q]);

                    break;
                case 'd':
                    System.out.println("Enter a catalog number between 0-9: ");
                    int o = inp.nextInt();
                    System.out.println(Faculty[o]);
                    break;

            }

            // Blank line, for formatting
            System.out.println("");

        } while (!userInput2.equals("q"));
        System.out.println("Done.");


    } else {
        //block 2 for students
        do {

            String[] Student = {"0. Alice Johnson", "1. Johnny Marr", "2. Johnny Johnson", "3. Robert Smith",
                "4. Ian Curtis", "5. Luke Shapiro", "6. David Newman", "7. Ren Newman", "8. Camille Kaslan", "9. Alexander Shulgin"};

            System.out.println("What would you like to do?");
            System.out.println("S: Search");
            System.out.println("E: Edit");
            System.out.println("D: Display");
            System.out.println("Q: Quit");

            // user input
            userInput3 = inp.nextLine().toLowerCase();
            System.out.println("");

            // Respond based on user input
            switch (userInput3.charAt(0)) {
                case 's':
                    System.out.println("Type part of the persons name: ");
                    String x = inp.nextLine().toLowerCase();
                    String[] y = Student;
                    Search(y, x);
                break;
                case 'e':
                    System.out.println("Enter the catalog number of the entry trying to edit: ");
                    int r = inp.nextInt();
                    System.out.println(Student[r]);
                    System.out.println("Enter new catalog information: ");
                    Student[r] = inp.nextLine();
                    System.out.println(Student[r]);
                    break;
                case 'd':
                    System.out.println("Enter a catalog number between 0-9: ");
                    int n = inp.nextInt();
                    System.out.println(Student[n]);
                    break;

            }

            // Blank line, for formatting
            System.out.println("");

        } while (!userInput3.equals("q"));
        System.out.println("Done.");



    }
```

In case it was unclear, the firsts issue is what to put in the for-loop inside of my search method called "search". The second question is how to take the new info from the user and replace it in the array of names (the edit feature).

Comment: So many questions in single question, I would suggest split into multiple questions and limit your question to the point

Comment: Yeah, I'm sorry guys, I just really have no idea what I'm doing. I have a hard time applying small bits of code into a larger code. I figured the best way to explain what I was doing was to put it all out on the table.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First question, maybe something like this?

```
public static void Search(String[] arr, String find) {
    for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
        if (arr[i].toLowerCase().contains(find.toLowerCase())) {
             System.out.println(String.format("found name: %s", arr[i]));
             return;
        }
    }
    System.out.println("Name not found!");
}
```

Second question is a common problem that comes up all the time on SO, you need to follow your nextInt with a nextLine to eat the newline character:

```
System.out.println("Enter the catalog number of the entry trying to edit: ");
int q = inp.nextInt();
inp.nextLine();
System.out.println(Faculty[q]);
```

Comment: I wish I could hug you over the internet!!!!!! But there's one small problem, the first bit of code has an error at the line:

  if (arr[i].toLowerCase().contains(find.toLowerCase()) {

It says " ')' expected "

any clue?

Comment: Found it! now it says ";" expected and says Requires: boolean but that I'm requesting String.

Comment: Should I post a new question asking about that smaller, more localized, problem?

Comment: @Clueless Yeah sorry I wrote it out in the code window, didn't test it out in a compiler, what was the other issue besides the paranthesis?

Answer (score 0):

If I have understood well what you need is:

```
"string1".equalsIgnoreCase("string2");
```

This would compare 2 strings ignoring if they are uppercase or lower. Now what you have to do is loop the array and compare each index to the String you want to compare.

Comment: I don't think that's it. I have two arrays that I created, and I need to prompt the user for new names to put into that string inside of the array. If that's what you're trying to do I must not understand.

Comment: We are the one who don't understand you.